# Can I define C functions that accept native Go types through CGo?

Tags: go, cgo

For the work I'm doing to integrate with an existing library, I ended up needing to write some additional C code to provide an interface that was usable through CGo.

In order to avoid redundant data copies, I would like to be able to pass some standard Go types (e.g. Go strings) to these C adapter functions.

I can see that there are `GoString` and `GoInterface` types defined in the header CGo generates for use by exported Go functions, but is there any way to use these types in my own function prototypes that CGo will recognise?

At the moment, I've ended up using `void *` in the C prototypes and passing `unsafe.Pointer(&value)` on the Go side.  This is less clean than I'd like though (for one thing, it gives the C code the ability to write to the value).

**Update:**

Just to be clear, I do know the difference between Go's native string type and C `char *`.  My point is that since I will be copying the string data passed into my C function anyway, it doesn't make sense to have the code on the Go side make its own copy.

I also understand that the string layout could change in a future version of Go, and its size may differ by platform.  But CGo is already exposing type definitions that match the current platform to me via the documented `_cgo_export.h` header it generates for me, so it seems a bit odd to talk of it being unspecified:

```
typedef struct { char *p; int n; } GoString;
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to use this definition in prototypes visible to CGo.  I'm not overly worried about binary compatibility, since the code making use of this definition would be part of my Go package, so source level compatibility would be enough (and it wouldn't be that big a deal to update the package if that wasn't the case).

Comment: I am running into this as well.  I wish I could forward declare typedefs for say GoInterface as _GoInterface but I cannot get that to work. `
// typedef struct GoInterface _GoInterface;
// extern void my_func(_GoInterface x);`

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You cannot safely mix, for example Go strings (`string`) and C "strings" (`*char`) code without using the provided helpers for that, ie. `GoString` and `CString`. The reason is that to conform to the language specs a full copy of the string's content between the Go and C worlds must be made. Not only that, the garbage collector *must* know what to consider (Go strings) and what to ignore (C strings). And there are even more things to do about this, but let me keep it simple here.

Similar and/or other restrictions/problems apply to other Go "magical" types, like `map` or `interface{}` types. In the interface types case (but not only it), it's important to realize that the inner implementation of an `interface{}` (again not only this type), *is not* specified and is implementation specific.

That's not only about the possible differences between, say gc and gccgo. It also means that your code will break at any time the compiler developers decide to change some detail of the (unspecified and thus non guaranteed) implementation.

Additionally, even though Go doesn't (now) use a compacting garbage collector, it may change and without some pinning mechanism, any code accessing Go run time stuff directly will be again doomed.

Conclusion: Pass only simple entities as arguments to C functions. POD structs with simple fields are safe as well (pointer fields generally not). From the complex Go types, use the provided helpers for Go strings, they exists for a (very good) reason.

Comment: I am aware that a Go string is not the same as a `char *`.  I'd prefer to avoid using `C.CString` since it copies the string data: I end up copying the data anyway in my glue function, so it seems a waste to perform another copy on the Go side.  And the details of the string format are already exposed in the `_cgo_export.h` header file CGo provides, so the details aren't exactly private.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a Go string to C is harder than it should be.  There is no really good way to do it today.  See https://golang.org/issue/6907.

The best approach I know of today is

```
// typedef struct { const char *p; ptrdiff_t n; } gostring;
// extern CFunc(gostring s);
import "C"

func GoFunc(s string) {
    C.CFunc(*(*C.gostring)(unsafe.Pointer(&s)))
}
```

This of course assumes that Go representation of a string value will not change, which is not guaranteed.